# Meaning of "Похоже, ты к нему клеишься"

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, лексикон

Похоже, ты к нему клеишься

Please let me know, which of the following translation is better for this?

1- Looks like you stick to him.
2- Sounds to me like you're going towards him.
3- Sounds to me like you fell in love with him!

Comment: Some context would help. Like, who says this to whom about whom and based on what observations. But yes, the answer by @БаянКупи-ка is the best possible guess.

Comment: and what is your preference and why you still have doubts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think any of the variants fits.

> It seems you're making a move on him
>   It seems you're hitting on him / trying to get with him

Answer (score 1):

All three are off, but 3 is the closest.

"Клеиться" in this case means "flirt" or "hit on". It describes an action, not a sentiment. The flirting might be inspired by anything from undying love to a passing interest.

Answer (score 0):

> Похоже, ты к нему клеишься
>
> 1- Looks like you stick to him.

No, because stick is about glue.

> 2- Sounds to me like you're going towards him.

No, because [going towards] is just a fact of phisically going up to somebody. It does not mean any love interest.

> 3- Sounds to me like you fell in love with him!

No, because fall in love is something deep and mental, but [клеить] is just about sex.

> Looks like you're picking up him.

To me this is the closest.

---

Here is imporant detail.

Direct litteral translation to Russian:

> Looks like you're picking up him.
> Похоже, ты его клеишь.

Direct litteral translation to English:

> Похоже, ты к нему клеишься.
> Looks like you're making him pick up you.

10-15 years ago pickuper was a man who professionally on constant basis [клеит] girls to have sex with them.

But today we live in the world where woman is the same or in feminist oriented countries even more rightfull than a man, so nowadays it is ok to say that a woman pickuped a man. But 10-15 years ago only a man could pickup a woman and a woman could be only pickuped. Therefore if it is initiative of woman to make a man to pick up her, we use passive voice.

[ты клеишься] - is passive voice - making yourself to be picked up by someone
[ты клеишь] - is active voice - you pick up someone

---

- [клеить] as [to pick up] is a slang word
- [клеить] means [to use glue to stick things together] or simply [to glue]